# Oracle Java 8 installation problem

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, java, oracle

I get the error below while trying to intall Oracle Java 8. Please tell me what's wrong.

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
[sudo] password for pragya: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Did u install java ? Check this by command : java --version

Comment: You probably didn't add the webupd8 PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Add this repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Then do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then jdk8

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Hope this works.